# How to deploy a jar on Windows server through Jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins

We have a jenkins job which is getting triggered after every push to gitlab.
It creates a build. Upon successful build we want to copy the jar to some Windows server. 
We are able to set SSH credentials for Linux server. How do we do it for Windows server.

Thanks

Comment: You can also do it on a Windows server: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server and after that use the publis-over-ssh plugin like you're using on linux

Answer (score 0):

Install the slave on windows machine & trigger the .bat file through jenkine's job.